# Drag and drop a folder to a website in chrome on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

Well, I'm looking to deploy a website using [Netlify Drop](https://app.netlify.com/drop), but it seems to me that drag & drop does not really work in Ubuntu, as far as dragging an item to chrome is concerned. So, my question is simple, is there any way I can do the above?

I'm using 20.04 LTS.